# How to write AWS Deployment script to launch AWS instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, deployment, scripting

I am looking to launch an AWS instance by deploying a script. However, I do not fully understand what this means. What should be in the script in order to launch it and how do I approach this in order to meet the following requirements?

> 1. User specifies AWS credentials in a separate key file;
> 2. User invokes termination script and pass the instance ID from
>      command line;
> 3. Termination script shuts down AWS instance.
> 4. Upon completion, the termination script returns message indicating 
>      whether the termination process has been completed successfully

I would appreciate some help in understanding what exactly a deployment script it and what language I should write it in. I have been coding thus far in Python and have created a script that *creates* an instance. But I am not sure how this is different from deploying an instance.

Comment: You should write your scripts in whichever language you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usage of the expressions "create an instance" and "deploy an instance" can mean the same thing or different things. Depends on the engineer's viewpoint.

Basically creating an EC2 instance means the AWS definition of launching an EC2 instance. Deploying an EC2 instance may include additional configuration details such as patching the OS, installing software and applications, etc. It is up to you to decide which is which and how each should be done.

When deploying an EC2 instance, I prefer to configure a machine exactly the way that I want with OS patches, software and my applications. Then I create an AMI. When I then launch a new EC2 instance, I use my hand created AMI. Then the new EC2 instance is exactly what I want. No long deployment phase.

Best practices when writing scripts. Do not store your Amazon credentials in your  scripts, source code, random files, etc. Install the Amazon CLI (Command Line Internface) tool and then configure the CLI with your credentials. Now your credentials are stored in a well defined location with the added benefit that Amazon SDKs, scripts, etc. will  know how to find the credentials and will automatically load and use them.

The easiest way of writing scripts to manage AWS services is to use the AWS CLI. Just about anything that you can do in the Amazon Management Console, you can do with the CLI. The CLI works on Windows, Linux and Mac OS.

[AWS Command Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)

Here is a CLI example that will terminate an EC2 instance. Replace with your instance ID:

```
aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids i-1234567890abcdef0
```

Writing your scripts in Python is another good idea. Managing AWS services with Python is very easy; there are lots of examples available on the Internet; and Python is just so easy and quick to develop Amazon apps. Use the Boto3 library and not the older Boto library. I use Python 3.x for all new development, but be aware that there is a lot of already created work on the Internet for AWS that runs under Python 2.x.

[CLI EC2 Commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/index.html#cli-aws-ec2)